# Can't get audio file to play

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming

I can't seem to figure out why my audio file won't play. The audio file is a wav file and is just. The error i am getting is  `javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException`.

```
public class MusicProgress {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame b = new JFrame();
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(b, "Pick a file: ", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.setVisible(true);
    final File file = new File(fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
    //URI directory = new URI (fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
    try {
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat audioFormat = inputStream.getFormat();
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for UnsupportedAudioFileException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843847/workaround-for-unsupportedaudiofileexception)

Comment: what file you are trying to play? Java support only .wav

Comment: it is trying to play a .wav file

Comment: Tell us what the stack trace says. Print `audioFormat` and tell us what it says (if it gets this far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not support all wav formats. The highest quality supported is a standard CD encoding format. With those files, you should be okay. That format has 16-bit encoding, 44100 fps, little endian, stereo. You should be able to inspect the properties of your wav file and learn if it matches or not.

It is getting more and more common for DAWs to produce wav files that have 24-bit or 32-bit encoding, or 48000fps or 92000fps.

It is possible to convert these to the "CD" encoding spec with a tool such as Audacity.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up some old code of mine to play an audio file. This might work:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SoundPlayer {

Clip clip;

public SoundPlayer(String file){

    //if(clip.isRunning()){clip.stop();}
    try{
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(SoundPlayer.class.getResource(file));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    }catch(Exception err){err.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SoundPlayer: "+err,null,0);}
}

}
```

And to play an audio clip:

```
new SoundPlayer(filepath);
```

The path should look somthing like this: "/game/resources/sound/Explosion.wav"
And as you stated, it must be a .wav file.

Comment: `final File file = new File(fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(MusicProgress.class.getResource(file.toString()));
   AudioFormat audioFormat = inputStream.getFormat();` 
This gives me an error `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @Sujinthan I copied your code exactly, and it worked.

Comment: can you tell me where you got your wav file. I think there is something wrong with my wav file.

Comment: @Sujinthan It very well could be. I tried multiple .wav files. Since i cant do product endorsement here, i cant give you a link. Just Google "Free sound"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use external libraries to play files like .mp3

> Java support only .wav

but that's enough.All you need is an external algorithm to play other music formats.All the other format's came originally from .wav they pass into an algorithm and then boom they become .ogg,.mp3,.whatever

1.A very impressive library to use which support .mp3 [JLayer.jar](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html)
You can import this jar into your project as an external library.

2.If you search more you will find [JAudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) it's just amazing but difficult to use.

3.Also  you can use Java Media FrameWork but whatever it doesnt support to much formats.

4.JavaZoom has also and other libraries to support **.ogg,.speex,.flac,.mp3**

Links to stackoverflow on  [How to play .wav files with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java)

And http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound
Not sure if that still works with java 8

This:

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;

   import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
   import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
   import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
   import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
   import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
   import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
   import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
   import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
   import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;


 public class AudioPlayerExample1 implements LineListener {

/**
 * this flag indicates whether the playback completes or not.
 */
boolean playCompleted;

/**
 * Play a given audio file.
 * @param audioFilePath Path of the audio file.
 */
void play() {
    File audioFile = new File("C:/Users/Alex.hp/Desktop/Musc/audio.wav");

    try {
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

        AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

        Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

        audioClip.addLineListener(this);

        audioClip.open(audioStream);

        audioClip.start();

        while (!playCompleted) {
            // wait for the playback completes
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        audioClip.close();

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

/**
 * Listens to the START and STOP events of the audio line.
 */
@Override
public void update(LineEvent event) {
    LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();

    if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
        System.out.println("Playback started.");

    } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        playCompleted = true;
        System.out.println("Playback completed.");
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AudioPlayerExample1 player = new AudioPlayerExample1();
    player.play();
}
```

}

Comment: No external library. So cannot use those.

Comment: what you mean no external library? You are coding on eclipse,netbeans,..?